# Validate on Update only if conditions are met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am working on adding some new validation to an app. The entire idea is to make sure that when a user updates their username it does not violate our username policy.

This is the current incantation of the validator:

```
validates_format_of :username, with: /[0-9a-zA-Z_]+/, 
on: :update,
if: lambda { |u| u.username_changed? }
```

Even with this validation bad characters make it through.

Here is my spec that I am using:

```
it "validates and does not update a user with an invalid username" do
  user.update_attributes(username: "k~!tten")
  expect(user.username).not_to eq "k~!tten"
end
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Username is "k~!tten" only on the model. It has not been saved to the database due to validation failure. Instead of:

```
expect(user.username).not_to eq "k~!tten"
```

use the below to assert that the username does not pass validation:

```
expect(user.username).not_to be_valid
```

Comment: You are correct sir, I changed it from expect(user).not_to be_valid to my spec in my post for testing.